# Getting null or empty when i want to show image from data in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, image

I want to dispaly image from database in Mvc but it show me null or empty error. Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: `contentPath`.

Please tell me any one what are my mistake in this code:

```
@foreach (tbl_AdminManageProducts item in @Model)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>@item.CategoryCode</td>
      <td>@item.ProductName</td>
      <td>@item.ProductPrice</td>
      <td>@item.ProductDetail</td>
      <td><img src="@Url.Content(item.ProductImage)" /></td>
      <td>@item.CompanyName</td>
    </tr>
  }
```

This is controller:

```
public class AdminController : Controller {
    // GET: /Admin/
    public ActionResult Index() {
        FYP_WISHEntities db = new FYP_WISHEntities();
        return View(db.tbl_AdminManageProducts.ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: item.ProductImage is null or empty in at least one of the items. That's what the message says.

Comment: sir what mean at least one of item ?

Comment: In your view you are looping through items: `tbl_AdminManageProducts item in @Model`. You should set a breakpoint on the following line and check all of them. `Url.Content()` is most likely throwing that exception because the `ProductImage` property doesn't contain anything in one of the collection's items.

Comment: @WajidCh Comment out the image tag code and simply print `item.ProductImage` value and you will see which one is null .So if it is null ,you need to make sure that you are not trying to call the Url.Content method on that.

Comment: @juunas thanku for explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to call the `Url.Content` method with a `NULL` value. The possible reason for this could be a null value is returned from the expression `item.ProductImage` for one of the iteration of your loop. So adding a null check would fix your error.

```
<td>
  @if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ProductImage))
  {
     <img src="@Url.Content(item.ProductImage)" />
  }
</td>
```

This code will try to render the image tag markup only if your item has a non null/non empty `ProductImage` property value.

`Url.Content` method takes a valid content path to the file. So make sure your `item.ProductImage` returns that when not null or empty.

Comment: Ok Thanks for help I got my solution